# Display prime factors of a positive number separated by '*' in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to find prime factors of positive number and separate them by '*', my function works, sometimes it prints two stars instead of one. `2*2**3`

```
void    ft_prime(int    n)
{
    int i;
    int y;

    i = 3;
    y = 0;
    while (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        ft_putnbr(2);
        ft_putchar('*');
        y = 1;
        n = n / 2;
    }
    while (i <= ft_sqrt(n))
    {
        while(n % i == 0)
        {
            if (y)
                ft_putchar('*');
            ft_putnbr(i);
            y = 1;
            n = n / i;
        }
        i += 2;
    }
    if (n > 2)
    {
        ft_putchar('*');
        ft_putnbr(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first loop, you print the number followed by the star. In the second loop, you print the star followed by the number. You should make the first loop exactly the same as the second loop.

Comment: @user3386109 if I do that I get a trailing `*`, like `2*2*3*`

Comment: add a condition that only prints the trailing `*` if there are remaining factors

Comment: @TenTenPeter I said make the **first** loop exactly like the second. Check `if(y)` and print the star *before* the number, **in the first loop**.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide by two to find the multiple of twos you first put the number (2) then the asterisk.
Inside the `while (i <= ft_sqrt(n))` used to find the rest of the primes you first print the asterisk then the number.

Why do you even have the first while?

In case you missed it this is a leading question.
The reason for finding the first prime, separate from the others is so you don't print the asterisk the first time.
At StackOverflow we don't like doing other people's homework but here's a lead:

Your code should look:

- Find the first divider (which may or may not be 2) and print it.
- Find the rest of the dividers to `ft_sqrt(n)` (if any) and print '*' then the prime.
- Deal with the remainder and either print the asterisk or not depending on whether you've printed anything (hint: what is `y` in your code for?).

Good design would call for a function to find the next divider.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have your other `ft_` functions, I write an example just use `putchar`, you can try to modify your own function like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void ft_prime(int n)
{
    int i;
    bool separated;

    separated = false;
    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        if (separated)
            putchar('*');
        putchar('2');
        n /= 2;
        separated = true;
    }

    i = 3;
    while (i <= n) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            if (separated)
                putchar('*');
            putchar(i+'0');
            n /= i;
            separated = true;
        }
        i += 2;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    ft_prime(12);
}
```

The output is

```
2*2*3
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your logic, the first loop: `(2*)(2*)`, the second loop:`(*3)`,
so the output is `(2*)(2*)(*3)`

To modify it, change the *first loop*, make the logic like (2)(*2)(*2)...

```
while (n % 2 == 0)
{
    if(y==1){
        ft_putchar('*');
    }
    ft_putnbr(2);
    y = 1;
    n = n / 2;
}
```